# Reducing generic arguments in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I am using generics in Java with a couple of classes.  I want to find a way to reduce the number of arguments I need to add.

```
public abstract class KeyValueProducer<O,K,V> {
  ....
}

public class KeyValueProducerMapper<O,K,V,KVP extends KeyValueProducer<O,K,V>> {

  public static <O,K,V,KVP extends KeyValueProducer<O,K,V>> KeyValueProducerMapper<O,K,V,KVP> create(Set<KVP> set) {
      return new KeyValueProducerMapper(set);
  }

  public KeyValueProducerMapper(Set<KVP> kvps) {
        ...
  }

  public V getVal(K key) {
      return map.get(key).getValue();       
  }
}
```

When I want to make an instance of my KeyValueProducerMapper, it looks like I need to write out:

```
Set<KVP> set;
....
KeyValueProducerMapper<K,V,O,KVP> kvpm = new KeyValueProducerMapper(set);
```

This seems kind of long and ridiculous.  Is there any way I can just define it like this?

```
KeyValueProducerMapper<KVP> kvpm = new KeyValueProducerMapper(set);
```

Comment: The answer is no, and you probably need to revisit your design if you feel things are not right.

Comment: Personally, I would have avoided using `KVP` (probably would have used `P` instead) as one of the generic substitutes.  Mostly because you're already using `K` and `V` as two other substitutes (Yes, I _know_ they're different, and that it's somewhat related anyways - but I just feel like that three-letter one is doing 'something else').

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your example what type parameters K, V and O are used for. But with such declaration of the `KeyValueProducerMapper` class you can't declare it as `KeyValueProducerMapper<KVP> = ...`. You have to declare it as `KeyValueProducerMapper<O,K,V,KVP> = ...` (using concrete types for O,K,V,KVP or specify those type params in the parent scope, i.e. method or class). The only alternative to this is to change the class declaration to not have type parameters K, V and O.

As for the right part of expression, you can use your static `create()` method without specifying type arguments, as the will be resolved from the left part of expression.

Comment: IF I define it as KeyValueProducerMapper<KVP>, can I have methods in in it that return types O,K, and V?  

I will always subclass KeyValueProducer with explicit types for K,V, and O if that helps any.

Comment: If they are specific types, you'll have specific types on those methods and don't need to declare type parameters. Like I said, these examples don't provide complete context for your question.

Comment: Yes, but you can have methods in the base class and just return type V.

Comment: It won't matter, since as you said, your subclass use a concrete type for V.